# Show field if true, hide field if false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to have a notification box displayed if amount in fieldA is higher than amount in fieldB.

Currently have some code working but the notification box toggles on and off not depending on the actual amount.

What am I missing?

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#fieldA').change(function(){
                if($(this).val()>$('#fieldb').val()){
                  //display it on the form
                  $('.labelNotification').toggle();
                  $('.labelNotification').append('Not recommended to have FieldA figure higher than FieldB.');
                }
            })
      });
```

HTML:

`< p style="display: none;" class="error labelNotification">`

Comment: I suspect if your if block which you are checking greater than is not working properly , print the values and see.

Comment: you're probably also missing some code that would remove the text you're appending once the condition is not met (i.e. FieldA < FieldB, but it wan't like that before)... in any case, try to alert what exactly you get as $(this).val() and $('#fieldb').val() as gov suggested... you can also try parseInt($(this).val()) and the same for FieldB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle is not the best approach for your situation.

You want to compare and then decide.

Since you are looking at numbers I would strongly suggest using a number type to do the comparison, either using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

The text in the notification label only needs to be set once, since you don't have any comment for it showing something when B > A. I would suggest setting this in your HTML.

```
<span class="labelNotification" style="display:none">Your Warning Text</span>
<!-- if your CSS class has `display:none` remove the style attribute -->
```

as for the jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $("#fieldA").change(function() {
       var a = parseInt($(this).val());
       var b = parseInt($("#fieldb").val());
       // handle if a or b is not a number -->  isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)

      if( a > b ) {
        $('.labelNotification').show()
      } else {
        $('.labelNotification').hide()
      }    
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Bobby, I'm using the exact top code but for some reason the notification message appears no matter if the value is lower or higher than fieldA - Any idea why that would be? Thank again!

Comment: Hey Alex, http://mymx.biz/SO/label-notification.htm has it working. keep in mind you have #fieldb with a lowercase b and #fieldA with an uppercase A. also I would recommend wiring change on both boxes as you will see in the example I posted. in this comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is tailor-made for the `toggle(boolean)` method. Also, you have to be careful about appending to the notification label ... what if the user changes his answer twice? It's better to have multiple notification objects, each of which can contain stuff for a single type of notification.

```
$(function() {
    $('#fieldA').change(function() {
        var isLarger = +$(this).val() > +$('#fieldB').val();  // Note: convert to number with '+'
        var $labelNotification = $('.labelNotification');
        $labelNotification.toggle(isLarger);
        if (isLarger) {
            //display it on the form
            $labelNotification.html('Not recommended to have FieldA figure higher than FieldB.');
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're comparing numerical values (which it seems like you are), you should use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) or [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp) to convert the (string) value returned by `val()` to an integer.  According to the [documentation for val](http://api.jquery.com/val/), the function always returns a string value.

Comment: The `>` comparison operator will convert them for you if they're strings. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SL4XA/

Comment: @patrick dw I don't think that's correct.  "10" > "2" evaluates to false, at least in FF.  Two strings are compared and there is no implicit conversion. http://jsfiddle.net/W46yq/

Comment: @ andrew the greater than is not issue , as patrick said it will be automatically taken care.

Comment: var a="30";
var b="20";

alert(a>b); firefox returns true for the above.

Comment: @gov That works because "2" comes before "3" in the alphabet.  Try "3" > "20".  This is the expected behavior, since the variables are compared as strings.

Comment: @Andrew - I think you must be right. That's strange. I'm pretty sure there's supposed to be a conversion. Perhaps that's just for arithmetic (except +).

Comment: Ah, there is type conversion *sometimes* as defined under **11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm** in the spec, but you're right, in this case you should convert. +1

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem ,

First thing is you need to have semicolon properly as below

```
    $('#fieldA').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() > $('#fieldB').val()) {
                alert("its greater");
                //display it on the form
$('.labelNotification').append('Not recommended to have FieldA figure higher than FieldB.');
 $('.labelNotification').show();               
            }
else {$('.labelNotification').hide();
$('.labelNotification').html('');}
        });
```

Second thing , when you toggle it it won't show for the second time

if 40 > 30

and again if you entery 50 and 50 > 30 it won't show

this is second problem

final problem is empty the label all the time

```
$('.labelNotification').html('')'
```

Comment: @alex , toggle does on/off based on its state , so it won't work if you constantly give a > b

Comment: What am I to use instead of TOGGLE?

Comment: @alex just use .show() or .hide() , inside if block use .show() and else block if they are not equal say .hide()